# SparkAR studio - How animation.driver.OnCompleted() should be implemented?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I have a simple plane driven by a scripted animation and what I want to achieve is to loop in a texture array with `driver.OnCompleted()`, as to switch to another texture when the animation completes, but my implementation doesn't work (throws no error but doesn't have any effect neither):

```
goodDriver.onCompleted().subscribe(function () {
    goodCount < goodList.items.length - 1 ? goodCount++ : goodCount = 0;
    goodMat.diffuse = goodList.items[goodCount].image_texture;
});
```

Not shown here but I have the array ready (based on the native picker example) and I moved this method in a function that is properly updated with no result.
Did some search here and there, also posted on FB dedicated group page (where you can watch my demo ;°) : https://www.facebook.com/groups/SparkARcommunity/775971819481529/?comment_id=776015786143799&notif_id=1575976197670849&notif_t=group_comment

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question ;°)

I didn't guessed that `OnCompleted()` relies on the `timeDriver.loopCount`, that was set to infinity, so it actually never completed!
So I just had to set the `loopCount` to 1 and then call `timeDriver.start()` in the above function.

Now it works!